# How to drop parentheses within column or data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
df = 

A  B
1  5
2  6)
(3  7
4  8
```

To remove parentheses I did:

```
df.A = df.A.str.replace(r"\(.*\)","")
```

But no result. I have checked a lot of replies here, but still same result.
Would appreciate to remove parentheses from the whole data set or at least in coulmn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to remove parentheses from the whole data set

With regex *character class* `[...]` :

```
In [15]: df.apply(lambda s: s.str.replace(r'[()]', ''))                                                    
Out[15]: 
   A  B
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  3  7
3  4  8
```

Or the same with `df.replace(r'[()]', '', regex=True)` which is a more concise way.

Comment: or if you do not want to use apply: `df.replace('[()]','', regex=True)`

Comment: But sometimes in my df there is no parentheses . So I get error : `AttributeError: ('Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas', 'occurred at index longitude_2')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want regex, you can use r"[()]" instead of alteration groups, as long as you need to replace only one character at a time.

```
df.A = df.A.str.replace(r"[()]", "")
```

I find it easier to read and alter if needed.